# MVC 5 built in validation message not showing for decimal types

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having an issue where the built in validation message does not show on fields that are decimal types.  Int types work as expected and do so without any data annotation.  I have the following model:

```
public class Expense
{
    public vwExpenseHeader ExpenseHeader { get; set;  }
    public tblExpenseDetail[] ExpenseDetail { get; set; }
}
```

In the view I have this:

```
            @for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExpenseDetail[i].Breakfast, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onblur = "setCategoryTotal(this.id);" } })</td>
            }
```

In the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Expense expense)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (AccountingClient acc = new AccountingClient())
                acc.ExpenseHeaderInsertOrUpdate(expense.ExpenseHeader, expense.ExpenseDetail);

            return View("Saved");
        }
        else
            return View(expense);
    }
```

The ModelState.IsValid call does work but no message appears on the field that failed validation.  For the int field

```
            @for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExpenseDetail[i].Mileage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onblur = "setCategoryTotal(this.id);" } })</td>
            }
```

it works as expected.  The message "Please enter a number." appears.

I have this partial class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(tblExpenseDetailMetaData))]
public partial class tblExpenseDetail
{
    public string DateOfExpenseString
    {
        get { return DateOfExpense.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); }
    }
}
```

and this metadata class

```
public class tblExpenseDetailMetaData
{
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Breakfast;
}
```

In the metadata class I've tried:

[Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid doubleNumber")]

and

[Range(0, 1000)]

Both the int and decimal are nullable types so I tried setting the decimal as a non-nullable type but same result.

Adding @Html.ValidationMessageFor works and I will likely have to use this approach but wouldn't need this if I could get the built in validation message to show.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but what in the world are you on about? `Html.ValidationMessageFor` shows the errors for a particular property, and you're saying that does in fact work, i.e. show the error as it should. What alternative are you looking for? If you're talking about `Html.ValidationSummary`, that only shows non-field errors when passed `true`, i.e. `Html.ValidationSummary(true)`, which is the default in scaffolded views. If you want it to show everything, then don't pass true to it: `Html.ValidationSummary()`

Comment: My bad.  New to MVC and was confusing the html5 number attribute on the input with what I thought was built in MVC validation.

Comment: The number input type is more about the control used that validation. The browser will do some basic valudation, forcing input to be numeric, but that's more a function of the control. If you use client-side validation, you get more precise validation and error messages, but that also requires the use of Html.ValidationMessageFor, since that's where the error will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. New to MVC and was confusing the html5 number attribute on the input with what I thought was built in MVC validation.